# What takes off more server resources/bandwidth

Tags: json, node.js, networking

I was wondering what takes more server resources/bandwidth:

Sending 1 JSON message that contains 6 objects, 
or
Sending 2 JSON MSG that contains 3 objects each.

(The data being sent is the same)

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: You could try it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending one request should consume less data due to overhead(a http request contain around 20 bytes of fixed headers alone).

If request size is an issue for you you also need to look at request type as well, due to different protocols having different overheads (eg : Web-socket overhead can be as low as 2 bytes while http fixed headers alone consume 20 bytes).

But even in a general sense the less request you make should consume less data due to the overhead added (in the same protocol), and it cannot be more since the content is the same.

Comment: Why does this depend upon the request type?  Sending all the data in one request is always going to be more efficient.

Comment: Yes it is as it is mentioned in the final sentence, but I was trying to convey the point that http, https, ws... overhead is different so that if he has the option of choosing the protocol since request size seems to be an issue for him he should choose the best for his requirement.

Comment: Well, the first line of your answer just seems misleading.  You say "it depends on your request type".  The question that is asked does not depend on the request type.  Fewer messages is always more efficient, no matter the request type.  You could improve your answer by editing that.